# Background Image Shouldn't Appear In Header In Drop Down Menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I've made a JavaScript dropdown menu. Everything works fine, except the background image. I have the image set to change when the dropdown menu is expanded, which also works fine.

The issue is with the headers. Unless the header is set to display `inline-block` or `inline`, the menu won't expand. When set to `inline-block` or `inline` everything expands when you click on the box. But if you click on the header itself, it adds the padding and border around the header and ads in the background image from the div. How do you prevent this from happening?

```
<div class="panel">
 <div class="collapse"><h2>Features</h2></div>
 <div class="elements">
  text<br>text<br>text
 </div>
</div>

<style>
h2 {/*display: inline-block;*/
    /*display: inline;*/
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;}

.expand,
.collapse {cursor: pointer;
           background-position: center right;
           background-repeat: no-repeat;
           background-color: #000033;
           border: 2px solid #990044;
           color: #ffffff;
           padding: 10px 0px;
           text-align: center;}

.collapse {background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABwAAAAcCAYAAAByDd+UAAABHUlEQVRIS+3USw6CMBAA0BYNutOjcAQ9iXHjhoXhBt4AEmwwbvQm6g04ii4hCLaNNRUp/dDgQllRPvMy05lC0PMFe/bAH7Re8R8qaYySTZGPoyBYXm3WMQwP04Gbhfd8FJDYtKTxNjkCCBf4Ni3y0dwWSrChm51wXI/FhjHaRXix5rKygtYwGr4C1QUitPdKUJ7xemILbcJw7JsDnBktqU20DfP9VfoaCxuoDCPJvc1hF1QF+wBNy6uKNYK6qA4mBFVRXawVlKHkPTfUbKJo65NuFJ1W0sNb1EjPgOQEUcakGbJIApRPQpoZ+1iaoQKqjCln2IJqYdpgrZGArEGaGke5pPzPZE/Juq0bjbtU9KPpc6MMTTGjPeyCfQV8AK4c2lwJRjQ3AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);}

.expand {background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABwAAAAcCAYAAAByDd+UAAABD0lEQVRIS+3Wyw2CQBAG4F1Q8KadSAnYgR0YL164SCWYKDHxonZgB1ICdiI3QR6yCgSVXXaAkGDkwgXyZf6dYcCo5Qu37KFugIaxH5FkdH1+hSYErpBgPck9E8j35AkUBYE5TEkqs6EoN1iApWmCUC6QgYHRUpCCOYk0zDUNV6VMkIYJSFAJFKLQim8glAqyME1b2AQ0zZ0CRQtBHiyNEop+gRCsCvoGVsGgaAbWwSDoE2wC40VxkxgPiteb7QFhPMsNsEPmLG196DZgolF0fFXYd614M47jhxvBCtEIXfy7rGZnKEq3k4jEZd3KPhMhcxqgYBV4gylZZaXf0qqR0t77g00n2pG/tjpl/37TPACe/d8VUJ3+EgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);}

.elements {background-color: #ccd9ff;
           overflow: hidden;}
</style>

<script>
function aaManageEvent (eventObj, event, eventHandler) {
 if (eventObj.addEventListener) {eventObj.addEventListener (event, eventHandler, false);}
 else if (eventObj.attachEvent) {event = "on" + event; eventObj.attachEvent (event, eventHandler);}
}
window.onload = function () {
 var divs = document.getElementsByTagName ("div");
 for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  if (divs[i].className == "collapse") {
   aaManageEvent (divs [i], "click", spring.expandOrCollapse);
  }
  else if (divs[i].className == "elements") {
   var height = divs [i].offsetHeight;
   divs [i] .height = height;
   if (divs [i] .id == "") divs [i].id = "div" + i;
   divs [i].style.height = "0";
  }
 }
}
var spring = {
 // adjust height
 adjustItem : function (val, newItem) {
  document.getElementById (newItem).style.height = val + "px";
 },
 // check if expand or collapse
 expandOrCollapse : function (evnt) {
  evnt = evnt ? evnt : window.event;
  var target = evnt.target ? evnt.target : evnt.srcElement;
  if (target.className == "collapse") spring.expand (target);
  else spring.collapse (target);
 },
 // Expand Panel
 expand : function (target) {
  target.className = 'expand';
  var children = target.parentNode.childNodes, panel;
  for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
   if (children [i].className == "elements") {
    panel = children [i]; break;
   }
  }
  var height = panel.height, incr = height / 20;
  for (var i=0; i < 20; i++) {
   var val = (i + 1) * incr;
   var func = "spring.adjustItem (" + val + ", '" + panel.id + "')";
   setTimeout (func, (i + 1) * 30);
  }
 },
 // Collapse Panel
 collapse : function (target) {
  target.className = "collapse";
  var children = target.parentNode.childNodes, panel;
  for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
   if (children [i].className == "elements") {
    panel = children [i]; break;
   }
  }
  var height = panel.height, decr = height / 20;
  for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
   var val = height - (decr * (i + 1));;
   var func = "spring.adjustItem (" + val + ", '" + panel.id + "')";
   setTimeout (func, (i + 1) * 30);
  }
 }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I click on the div, the dropdown works. But when I click on the header, I see an error in the browser console.

I think because when clicking on the `<h2>Features</h2>` element, the click event bubbles up to the `<div class="collapse">`, making the `var target` in this line not the `<div class="collapse">` but the `<h2>`:

```
var target = evnt.target ? evnt.target : evnt.srcElement;
```

A possible solution to fix this is for example to add an id to this line:

```
<div id="header" class="collapse"><h2>Features</h2></div>
```

Then you can directly get that div by id and change the classname.
I've adjusted your `expandOrCollapse` function to make it toggle based on the classname from the div with id="header".

For example:

```js
function aaManageEvent (eventObj, event, eventHandler) {
 if (eventObj.addEventListener) {eventObj.addEventListener (event, eventHandler, false);}
 else if (eventObj.attachEvent) {event = "on" + event; eventObj.attachEvent (event, eventHandler);}
}
window.onload = function () {
 var divs = document.getElementsByTagName ("div");
 for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  if (divs[i].className == "collapse") {
   aaManageEvent (divs [i], "click", spring.expandOrCollapse);
  }
  else if (divs[i].className == "elements") {
   var height = divs [i].offsetHeight;
   divs [i] .height = height;
   if (divs [i] .id == "") divs [i].id = "div" + i;
   divs [i].style.height = "0";
  }
 }
}
var spring = {
 // adjust height
 adjustItem : function (val, newItem) {
  document.getElementById (newItem).style.height = val + "px";
 },
 // check if expand or collapse
 expandOrCollapse : function (evnt) {
  var header = document.getElementById('header');
  if (header.className === "collapse") {
    spring.expand(header);
  } else {
    spring.collapse(header);
  }
 },
 // Expand Panel
 expand : function (target) {
  target.className = 'expand';
  var children = target.parentNode.childNodes, panel;
  for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
   if (children [i].className == "elements") {
    panel = children [i]; break;
   }
  }
  var height = panel.height, incr = height / 20;
  for (var i=0; i < 20; i++) {
   var val = (i + 1) * incr;
   var func = "spring.adjustItem (" + val + ", '" + panel.id + "')";
   setTimeout (func, (i + 1) * 30);
  }
 },
 // Collapse Panel
 collapse : function (target) {
  target.className = "collapse";
  var children = target.parentNode.childNodes, panel;
  for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
   if (children [i].className == "elements") {
    panel = children [i]; break;
   }
  }
  var height = panel.height, decr = height / 20;
  for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
   var val = height - (decr * (i + 1));;
   var func = "spring.adjustItem (" + val + ", '" + panel.id + "')";
   setTimeout (func, (i + 1) * 30);
  }
 }
};
```

```css
h2 {/*display: inline-block;*/
    /*display: inline;*/
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;}

.expand,
.collapse {cursor: pointer;
           background-position: center right;
           background-repeat: no-repeat;
           background-color: #000033;
           border: 2px solid #990044;
           color: #ffffff;
           padding: 10px 0px;
           text-align: center;}

.collapse {background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABwAAAAcCAYAAAByDd+UAAABHUlEQVRIS+3USw6CMBAA0BYNutOjcAQ9iXHjhoXhBt4AEmwwbvQm6g04ii4hCLaNNRUp/dDgQllRPvMy05lC0PMFe/bAH7Re8R8qaYySTZGPoyBYXm3WMQwP04Gbhfd8FJDYtKTxNjkCCBf4Ni3y0dwWSrChm51wXI/FhjHaRXix5rKygtYwGr4C1QUitPdKUJ7xemILbcJw7JsDnBktqU20DfP9VfoaCxuoDCPJvc1hF1QF+wBNy6uKNYK6qA4mBFVRXawVlKHkPTfUbKJo65NuFJ1W0sNb1EjPgOQEUcakGbJIApRPQpoZ+1iaoQKqjCln2IJqYdpgrZGArEGaGke5pPzPZE/Juq0bjbtU9KPpc6MMTTGjPeyCfQV8AK4c2lwJRjQ3AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);}

.expand {background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABwAAAAcCAYAAAByDd+UAAABD0lEQVRIS+3Wyw2CQBAG4F1Q8KadSAnYgR0YL164SCWYKDHxonZgB1ICdiI3QR6yCgSVXXaAkGDkwgXyZf6dYcCo5Qu37KFugIaxH5FkdH1+hSYErpBgPck9E8j35AkUBYE5TEkqs6EoN1iApWmCUC6QgYHRUpCCOYk0zDUNV6VMkIYJSFAJFKLQim8glAqyME1b2AQ0zZ0CRQtBHiyNEop+gRCsCvoGVsGgaAbWwSDoE2wC40VxkxgPiteb7QFhPMsNsEPmLG196DZgolF0fFXYd614M47jhxvBCtEIXfy7rGZnKEq3k4jEZd3KPhMhcxqgYBV4gylZZaXf0qqR0t77g00n2pG/tjpl/37TPACe/d8VUJ3+EgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);}

.elements {background-color: #ccd9ff;
           overflow: hidden;}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
 <div id="header" class="collapse"><h2>Features</h2></div>
 <div class="elements">
  text<br>text<br>text
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @CDM Nice! You are welcome. If this helped you solve your problem, you might consider choosing an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your declaration block of `h2` as shown below. This will solve your problem.

```
h2 {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    pointer-events: none;   // this line solves your problem.
}
```

CSS property `pointer-events` let you control under what circumstances an element can become the target of mouse events. when you set it to `none`, the element will never be the target of mouse events. So, the click event passed on to its descendant elements (here the box).